# AQL different results from stream UDF depending on output style (table, json)

Tags: lua, udf, aerospike, aql

I'm trying to create aggregation (map | reduce) with UDF but something is wrong on the very begining. In Aerospike I have a set with bin 'u' (secondary index) and bin 'v' which is a list of objects (auctions with transactions lists and other auction data) and I have a stream UDF to aggregate internal structure of 'v':

```
function trans_sum_by_years(s)
    local function transform(rec)

        local l = map()
        local x = map()
        local trans, auctions = 0, 0


        for i in list.iterator(rec['v'] or list()) do
            auctions = auctions + 1
            for t in list.iterator(i['t'] or list()) do
                trans = trans + 1
                date = os.date("*t", t['ts'])


                if l[date['year']] ~= nil then
                    l[date['year']] = l[date['year']] + t['price'] * t['qty']
                else
                    l[date['year']] = t['price'] * t['qty']
                end
            end
        end

        x.auctions = auctions
        x.trans = trans
        x.v = l
        return x
    end

    return s : map(transform)

end
```

The problem is that output is very diffrent depending on setting output on table or json. In first case it seems everything is OK:

```
{"trans":594, "auctions":15, "v":{2010:1131030}}            
{"trans":468, "auctions":68, "v":{2011:1472976, 2012:5188}} 
......
```

On second I get empty object from internal record aggregation.
    {
        "trans_sum_b...": {
             "trans": 389,
             "auctions": 89,
             "v": {}
        }
    },
    {
        "trans_sum_b...": {
            "trans": 542,
            "auctions": 30,
            "v": {}
         }
    }
    .....

I prefer json output and wasted couple hours to find out why I get empty 'v' field without success. So my question is "what the hell is going on" ;-) If my code is correct, what is wrong with the json output, that I don't see the results. If my code is wrong, why it's wrong and why table output results with what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple as hell. But I'm new in Aerospike/Lua and I don't trust my knowledge so I searched for error everywhere but within AQL/UDF area. The problem is more fundamental and interferes with the specification of the JSON itself.

Keys in JSON have to be strings! So `tostring(date['year'])` solves problem.

Other question is does it is a bug or a feature :-) If Aerospike's map type allow integer keys should there be automatic key conversion from integer to string to satisfy JSON specification or not? IMHO there should be but probably some people disagree claiming that map type is not for integer keys...

Answer (score 0):

**@user1875438 Your code is correct. It seems that there is bug in aql.**
My result is the same as yours, the field of v is empty when using json mode.
I used `tcpdump` to grab the responses of aerospike-server when running these two commands, and found out the responses are the same, so I think it's very possible there is bug in aql tool.

```
159   0x0050:  0001 0000 0027 0113 0007 5355 4343 4553  .....'....SUCCES
160   0x0060:  5383 a603 7472 616e 7301 a903 6175 6374  S...trans...auct
161   0x0070:  696f 6e73 01a2 0376 81cd 07ce 01         ions...v.....
162 01:57:38.255065 IP localhost.hbci > localhost.57731: Flags [P.], seq 98:128, ack 144, win 42853, options [nop,nop,TS val 976630236 ecr 976630223], length 30
163   0x0000:  4500 0052 55f8 4000 4006 0000 7f00 0001  E..RU.@.@.......
```

I just posted an issue [here](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-server/issues/127).